# How can I get back an upvote for a comment under a question?

Tags: support

I have given an up vote to an incorrect comment under one of my questions. I click on in to take it back but that does not work. How can I take back my upvote to a comment where there is no downvote button?

Comment: You probably can't any more. See [Cancelling upvote on comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1170) in the Meta site for StackExchange.